# Hide extra stars when narrowed to subtree

Tags: org-mode, narrowing

I have an outline with many levels of indentation. When I narrow to a particular subtree, I would like to hide the extra stars (and indentation) so that It looks like I am working on a top-level heading.

So for example, this

```
****** Deeply indented heading
Some text
```

becomes this

```
* Deeply indented heading
Some text
```